# fragment: no view found for id ，because it's parent view has been removed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewgroup

As title, a view contains a fragment. Because of the method `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` is asynchronous, the parent view of fragment maybe be removed when the fragment commits succeed. The fragment can't find the parent view by id, so the app will crash. what can I do it ?

Comment: check activity `isFinishing()` before committing `fragment` asynchronously

Comment: just don't remove the view

Comment: @rajanks thanks for comment.but not activity, only its parent view is removed.

Comment: @vladyslavmatviienko  thanks. Because of business needs，the view maybe be removed.Is there anything else besides this method?

Comment: then just check if it has been removed, and replace fragment only in case if it is not removed

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of two ways

**Check null on view before replacing**

```
  if(parentView != null){
     // do commit here
  }
```

**Ignore Exception to avoid Crash**

```
 try{
   //do commit here
 }catch(Exception ignored){}
```